# I'm getting a syntax error when I try to make an array. Chaos game

Tags: python, arrays, geometry

I'm trying to make a program that will create a Sierpinski triangle, but I keep getting a syntax error. This is what I have so far:

```
import sys, pygame, random, math, array

pygame.init()

w, h = size = 400, 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Project 1, Spierpinski triangle")

verticies = [(1,h - 1), (int(w/2), 1), (w-1,h-1)]

for v in verticies:
    screen.set_at(v, (0,0,255))

yRand = random.randint(0,h-1)
xRand = (random.randint(yRand,(w - yrand)*2)
point = [yRand,xRand]

for i in range(50000):
    v = random.choice(verticies)
    point = (int((point[0] + v[0])/2), int((point[1] + v[1])/2))
    screen.set_at(point,(255,255,255))
```

I get a syntax error at point

Comment: Missing a closing `)` on this line: `xRand = (random.randint(yRand,(w - yrand)*2)`

Comment: what is `xrand` and `yrand` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing a closing bracket here:

```
xRand = (random.randint(yRand, (w - yrand) * 2))
                                               ^
```

Also, you have a spelling error, it should be `yRand` not `yrand`.

Comment: OHHhHHH.  Thanks so much. i hate myself now.